# Unable to get data from python web scraper because the application is opening the page in new window

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request

I have this website which is created in JAVA and it only allow you to see data once you are logged in..
Now when i login it just open the page in new window with all its logged in information but then when copy the link and paste in the same window it works here are some images..

Link to login page
    https://agency-pia.crane.aero/
Image of login page
[image]

Link that comes after login
    https://agency-pia.crane.aero/JSF/RezvEntry.xhtml?faces-redirect=true
image that comes after login
[image]

Now any way what i am willing to do is to create a software that scrapes this website or web application..

```
``import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36'
}

login_data = {
    'name': '<username>',
    'pass': '<password>',
    'form_id': 'new_login_form',
    'op': 'Login'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    url = 'https://agency-pia.crane.aero/'
    r = s.post(url, data=login_data, headers=headers)
    print(r.text)
    url = 'https://agency-pia.crane.aero/JSF/RezvEntry.xhtml?faces-redirect=true'
    r = s.get(url, headers=headers)``
```

So I create an application in python but i am unable to get that to work it logins OK but don't really gets the other page that comes after the login..

I have tried everything but i don't know what am i doing wrong..

What i want is when i login then i should access any page from the website..

Comment: You can use selenium instead of Beautiful Soup.

Comment: i can but the problem is not with Beautiful Soup its with the page access the website don't allow me to get the data

Comment: the images are both redirected to some no-access [placeholder](https://internetseekho.com/wp-content/plugins/media-ace/assets/hotlink-placeholder.png) - can you please download the original images and edit your question to upload them from disk?

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign random names like `name` and `pass` in `login_data={}`.It should be the exact value in the HTML of the site . And also you cant just send a POST request to the site and expect it to log you in it should contain the `<form>` tags' `action` value (which is  `action="MemberRezvEntry.jsp"` in your case) and also every hidden inputs should be included in the payload to prevent any probable errors.

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()
payload = {'ORACLE_DEBUG_MODE':'','paxInfo':'','USERNAME': 'name', 'PASSWORD': 'pswd123'}
r = s.post('https://agency-pia.crane.aero/MemberRezvEntry.jsp', data=payload)
result = s.get(' https://agency-pia.crane.aero/JSF/RezvEntry.xhtml?faces-redirect=true').text
print(result)
```

or you may use the custom cookie after logging in your site and use it in your bot

```
url = 'https://agency-pia.crane.aero/JSF/RezvEntry.xhtml?faces-redirect=true'
headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2227.0 Safari/537.36'}
cookies = {#custom cookies from browser}

s = requests.Session()
r = s.post(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
```

Comment: It probably can't be done using requests try using `selenium`